# make a link in column Data table YUI

Tags: yui

I have a web page that contains a data table I want to make the first column cells redirect the user to another pages depend on its value so I want first to get the value from a cell second to make a link from this cell to another page depend on that value.

any advises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write a custom cell formatter.  Check the documentation for whichever version of YUI you are using:

YUI 2: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/datatable/#format

YUI 3: http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/datatable/#formatters